# Code-Cracker puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, word

> Each number in our Code-Cracker grid represents a different letter of the alphabet (for example, today 26 represents D). You have two letters in the control grid to start you off. Enter them in the matching squares in the main grid and solve the starter word.  Fill in other squares in the main and control grid with the find letters and look for the next word. Follow the word trail through the puzzle to its completion.

```
01 XX 02 XX 03 XX XX XX 04 XX 05 XX 06
07 08 09 06 10 11 XX 08 07 12 12 10 11
13 XX 14 XX 13 XX 07 XX 15 XX 09 XX 09
13 07 11 07 01 14 16 XX 10 17 18 09 08
10 XX 01 XX 19 XX 20 XX 17 XX 10 XX 11
01 14 17 10 XX 04 21 14 17 10 XX XX XX
07 XX 19 XX 13 XX 14 XX 10 XX 01 XX 07
XX XX XX 08 14 01 01 19 XX 16 03 07 01
07 XX 22 XX 12 XX 01 XX 23 XX 09 XX 01
24 14 10 22 10 XX 10 25 10 16 21 01 10
14 XX 12 XX 07 XX 26 XX 12 XX 04 XX 23
26 14 22 10 12 01 XX 23 14 24 03 07 05
10 XX 10 XX 23 XX XX XX 01 XX 01 XX 01
```

- 24: S
- 26: D

---

This is taken from a local newspaper:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> ```
>  T     J     H           G     P     K 
>  A  W  O  K  E  N     W  A  R  R  E  N 
>  F     I     F     A     Z     O     O 
>  F  A  N  A  T  I  C     E  L  B  O  W 
>  E     T     Y     Q     L     E     N 
>  T  I  L  E     G  U  I  L  E 
>  A     Y     F     I     E     T     A 
>           W  I  T  T  Y     C  H  A  T 
>  A     V     R     T     M     O     T 
>  S  I  E  V  E     E  X  E  C  U  T  E 
>  I     R     A     D     R     G     M 
>  D  I  V  E  R  T     M  I  S  H  A  P 
>  E     E     M           T     T     T
> ```